# Textfield validation in Grails framework

Tags: validation, grails

I am new to grails. I want to validate a text field and throw error message on the screen. Can anyone help me on this. for eg.lastName is not entered .

here is my code
Person.groovy
class Person {

```
String firstName
String lastName
int age
static constraints = {
    lastName(nullable:false, blank:false)
    }
```

gsp

LastName

```
    <label for="firstName">FirstName</label>
<g:textField name="firstName" value="${person.firstName}"></g:textField><br/>
<label for="age">Age</label>
<g:textField name="age" value="${person.age}"/><br/>
<g:actionSubmit value ="save" action="save"/>
```

i tried the above but it is not working. do i need to make any setting for validation. I am trying this in intelliJ

Comment: what exactly is not working?

Answer (score 1):

your code works as it should
you are not handling any error, you should at least use something to flash a message on errors. 
you might wanna try something like this:

```
 <g:textField name="firsname" value="${person.firstname}"/>
            <g:hasErrors bean="${person}" field="firstname">
                    <g:eachError bean="${person}" field="firstname">
                        <p style="color: red;"><g:message error="${it}"/></p>
                    </g:eachError>
                </g:hasErrors>
```